# Equivalent in c# for a 'Base64' Encoded string of encrypted bytes generated in c programming to be sent in URL query string

Tags: c#, c++, string, encoding, base64

I used this code from the web. But the result which is generated in c program did not match the c# encoding (ASCII, UTF-8 etc.,).

What is the best way to handle characters in c to overcome this?

This is for windows based exe.

For the text "Í£kúæ›Ì"

```
in VC I get Base64 Encoded string as "zaNr+uabzADMzMzMpGICvnj/GAA2IUEAAQAAAA=="
```

but in C# I get different results based on the encoding type

```
UTF-8 = > "K0FNMEFvdy1rK0FQb0E1aUE2QU13LQ=="
UTF-7 = > "w43Co2vDusOm4oC6w4w="
```

etc....
What encoding / no encoding in C# would get me the same result as the C Program.

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include "base64.h"

static const unsigned char pr2six[256] =
{
    /* ASCII table */
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 62, 64, 64, 64, 63,
    52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
    15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
    41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64
};

int Base64decode_len(const char *bufcoded)
{
    int nbytesdecoded;
    register const unsigned char *bufin;
    register int nprbytes;

    bufin = (const unsigned char *) bufcoded;
    while (pr2six[*(bufin++)] <= 63);

    nprbytes = (bufin - (const unsigned char *) bufcoded) - 1;
    nbytesdecoded = ((nprbytes + 3) / 4) * 3;

    return nbytesdecoded + 1;
}

int Base64decode(char *bufplain, const char *bufcoded)
{
    int nbytesdecoded;
    register const unsigned char *bufin;
    register unsigned char *bufout;
    register int nprbytes;

    bufin = (const unsigned char *) bufcoded;
    while (pr2six[*(bufin++)] <= 63);
    nprbytes = (bufin - (const unsigned char *) bufcoded) - 1;
    nbytesdecoded = ((nprbytes + 3) / 4) * 3;

    bufout = (unsigned char *) bufplain;
    bufin = (const unsigned char *) bufcoded;

    while (nprbytes > 4) {
    *(bufout++) =
        (unsigned char) (pr2six[*bufin] << 2 | pr2six[bufin[1]] >> 4);
    *(bufout++) =
        (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[1]] << 4 | pr2six[bufin[2]] >> 2);
    *(bufout++) =
        (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[2]] << 6 | pr2six[bufin[3]]);
    bufin += 4;
    nprbytes -= 4;
    }

    /* Note: (nprbytes == 1) would be an error, so just ingore that case */
    if (nprbytes > 1) {
    *(bufout++) =
        (unsigned char) (pr2six[*bufin] << 2 | pr2six[bufin[1]] >> 4);
    }
    if (nprbytes > 2) {
    *(bufout++) =
        (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[1]] << 4 | pr2six[bufin[2]] >> 2);
    }
    if (nprbytes > 3) {
    *(bufout++) =
        (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[2]] << 6 | pr2six[bufin[3]]);
    }

    *(bufout++) = '\0';
    nbytesdecoded -= (4 - nprbytes) & 3;
    return nbytesdecoded;
}

static const char basis_64[] =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

int Base64encode_len(int len)
{
    return ((len + 2) / 3 * 4) + 1;
}

int Base64encode(char *encoded, const char *string, int len)
{
    int i;
    char *p;

    p = encoded;
    for (i = 0; i < len - 2; i += 3) {
    *p++ = basis_64[(string[i] >> 2) & 0x3F];
    *p++ = basis_64[((string[i] & 0x3) << 4) |
                    ((int) (string[i + 1] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
    *p++ = basis_64[((string[i + 1] & 0xF) << 2) |
                    ((int) (string[i + 2] & 0xC0) >> 6)];
    *p++ = basis_64[string[i + 2] & 0x3F];
    }
    if (i < len) {
    *p++ = basis_64[(string[i] >> 2) & 0x3F];
    if (i == (len - 1)) {
        *p++ = basis_64[((string[i] & 0x3) << 4)];
        *p++ = '=';
    }
    else {
        *p++ = basis_64[((string[i] & 0x3) << 4) |
                        ((int) (string[i + 1] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
        *p++ = basis_64[((string[i + 1] & 0xF) << 2)];
    }
    *p++ = '=';
    }

    *p++ = '\0';
    return p - encoded;
}


int main() {
   char mysrc[] = "Hello world...";

    char mysrc[] = "Í£kúæ›Ì";
    char myb64[1024] = "";
    char mydst[1024] = "";

    //Base64encode(myb64, mysrc, 28);
    Base64encode(myb64, mysrc, strlen(mysrc); //corrected
    printf("The string\n[%s]\nencodes into base64 as:\n[%s]\n", mysrc, myb64);
    printf("\n");
    Base64decode(mydst, myb64);
    printf("The string\n[%s]\ndecodes from base64 as:\n[%s]\n", myb64, mydst);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: added example to better explain the problem

Answer (score 2):

You could try with the `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")`, so

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
string base64Encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(encoding.GetBytes("Í£kúæ›Ì"));
```

Note that in general yours is a very complex question... See for example https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html the page of gcc about the encoding of source files.

Note that this response is in general wrong... because the problem is quite complex. A `char*` in C/C++ is more similar to an unencoded byte array than to a string. 
A string constant contained in a C source file (a `"something"`) is a byte array encoded in the encoding of the source file. In Visual Studio you can select it by doing File->SaveAs, then clicking on the little arrow of the Save button, Save With Encoding. For example:

```
printf("%d", strlen("è"));
```

will print *1* if the encoding of the file is Windows-1252, *2* if the encoding of the file is utf-8.

So if you want to encode in the same way in C#, you have to do `Encoding.GetEncoding("encodingName")` (or `Encoding.UTF8` if the C/C++ file was UTF8 encoded)

**but this is only for string constants!**

If for example you do a `scanf("%s", str)` (so you accept a string from the console), the encoding of the bytes in the `str` will be the encoding of the console. If you take a string from a windows control, then the encoding will be the default encoding of Windows (so `Encoding.Default` in C#). If you read an external file, then the `char*` will be the bytes of the file, so the encoding of the `char*` will be the encoding of the file.

Comment: I do not see the support for Encoding "8859-1" in .net, can i try any other one?

Comment: @Bojan It was `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")`... cut a piece :-)

Comment: @@xanatos yeah! I got a little closer. your code gave the following result "zaNr+uY+zA==" but is shorter than what I get from the c program "zaNr+uabzADMzMzMpGICvnj/GAA2IUEAAQAAAA=="

Comment: @Bojan Read the expanded response, and note that `Base64encode(myb64, mysrc, 28);` is **wrong**... You should use `strlen(mysrc)` instead of 28.

Comment: @Bojan There is a good chance that your C/C++ file is in truth Windows-1252 encoded (so `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`). Go to File->Save As, click on the little arrow near the save button, Save With Encoding to see the exact encoding. There are very small differences between the 1252 and the 8859-1 (like the `€` character, not present in 8859-1)

Comment: so what do u think could work here, could an in memory comparison of bytes would do the trick, rather than decoding it and storing in a string/ file.

Comment: @Bojan I don't know what you want to do... I don't think that the code you wrote is representative of what you want to obtain... It would be too much simple to only calculate the Base64 of some "fixed" (written in the source file) strings... The encoding is always defined by the "source" of the data, and C will always treat strings as byte arrays (`char*`)

Comment: @Bojan In general try with `Encoding.Default`, if possible try to check strings with a `€` inside and some letters like the ones you were using `Í£kúæ›Ì` and see what happens. If it doesn't work, try `ISO-8859-1`. Then try UTF8.

Comment: Got your point. The greater problem that I am trying to solve here is to Base64 encode an encrypted data(from c prog) that I will send it over the url and on the server (C#) would decode and decrypt the same.

Comment: @Bojan Encrypted data doesn't have an encoding (unless you use very poor encoding, like Caesar's Crypt). It is "random" bytes. For this reason you then Base64 it, to make it "readable". So there is no encoding here. In C you have a `char*` with a `len`. You base64 it. In C# you de-base64 the text you received and you decrypt it.

Comment: How do I de-base64 without using encoding. I tried both "ISO-8859-1" and 1252 but both do not match.

Comment: @Bojan What is the source of the data? It is the source of the data that "decides" the encoding.

Comment: What I see in the source is have is only bit operations and it gets stored in unsigned char variables. We have various sources like  AES, Twofish,Threefish etc.,

Answer (score 0):

**Encode**

```
string base64Encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("my string"));
// base64Encoded = "bXkgc3RyaW5n"
```

**Decode**

```
string base64Decoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encoded));
// base64Decoded = "my string"
```

Comment: the c program is not equivalent the one generated by C# with UTF-8 Encoding.